# Regex In body of API test

Tags: regex, google-cloud-datastore, google-apis-explorer

I'm testing API with https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/lookup

The following brings a found result with data. I would like to use a regular expression with bring back all records with name having the number 100867. All my attempts result wit a missing result set.
i.e. change to `"name": "/1000867.*/"`

```
            {
"keys": [
    {
    "path": [
        {
        "kind": "Job",
        "name": "1000867:100071805:1"
        }
    ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Google documentation for lookup key states that the name is a "string" and that

> The name of the entity. A name matching regex `__.*__` is reserved/read-only. A name must not be more than 1500 bytes when UTF-8 encoded. Cannot be "".

The regex part threw me off and the solution was to use runQuery!
Consider this closed.